# Stripe API and autoPagingIterator() with PHP max execution time

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I'm looking into the Stripe API and the autoPagingIterator() to work through lists of resources and store in a database the current position of the Stripe Account.

I'm writing this in PHP and I'm wondering how this can be used and not end up timing out the PHP script?

How's best to work through a large list while not having scripts time out while still using the autoPagingIterator()

EDIT: and without ramping up the max_execution time.

Eventually, the app will have to handle various sized stripe accounts and need to "import" them as a process (without killing the server) - it's OK if this import process takes a little time for each connected account.

Comment: This sort of process should be done in the background, not with a web page. By default, PHP CLI has no maximum execution time.

Comment: Thank you :) I cannot accept this as an answer though as it's only a comment.